# Call to a member function any() on string in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to access the `$errors` variable to my view but it returns an error. Please see my code below.

**Controller**

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [...]);

if($request->required == 1){
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [...]);
}


if($validator->fails()){
  return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

**View**

```
@if($errors->any())
  ... Some HTML code here
@endif
```

**Error**

> Call to a member function any() on string

Any idea? This should work, but it is not.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Laravel version: 5.5

Comment: That example uses `$request->validate([...]);` only though, no `if($validator->fails()){...`

Comment: Have you tried `@dd($errors)` on your view? it should be an object of type `Illuminate/Support/ViewErrorBag`

Comment: @kerbholz Check this link, we can still use that approach. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#manually-creating-validators

Comment: @Helioarch it returns an empty `ViewErrorBag`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your line as per below:

From

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
```

To

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput();
```

Then in you blade file you can access it as:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Do you have any explanation or reference for this?

Comment: @Jonjie You can find refereance here how to access error message. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#working-with-error-messages

Comment: @Jonjie Thanks for accepting my answer..pls. do up votes if it has solved your concern.

Comment: May I ask why do we need to use `->errors()`?  This documentation says that we need to pass the `$validator` instead of `$validator->errors()`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#manually-creating-validators

Comment: As per the document it should be available in the view, but if in case it is not accessible you can also try above solution. also in controller make sure you are getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

I use validation in view like this below

```
<div class="{{'form-group required'.$errors->first('name',' has-error')}}">
     <label>Title</label>
     <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
     <div class="text-danger">{{$errors->has('name') ? $errors->first('name') : ''}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice handling of error. But not exactly what I need to do.

Comment: getting error `Call to a member function has() on string`, not solved my issue yet.